# Convert string back to range

Tags: vba, excel

In the code below, I am converting range to string in the line:

```
dCostCenter = Right(dCostCenter, Len(dCostCenter) - 1)
```

However, I need to use `dCostCenter` as range again in the line:

```
Set DetailsTargetCell = forecastMain.Cells(dCostCenter.Row, dMonth.Column)
```

otherwise I get an "Object required" error.

But is it possible to convert string to range? Or maybe there is another way to solve this?

```
Public Function SetDetailsTarget(monthNumber As Integer, CCNumber As String)

Call SetWorkbooks
Call SetRanges

For Each dMonth In DetailsMonths 
    For Each dCostCenter In DetailsCostCenters
        If Left(dCostCenter, 1) = "0" And Not dCostCenter Like "*/*" Then
                dCostCenter = Right(dCostCenter, Len(dCostCenter) - 1)'range to string
        End If
        If monthNumber <> "0" Then
            If dMonth = MonthName(monthNumber) And dCostCenter = CCNumber Then
                Set DetailsTargetCell = forecastMain.Cells(dCostCenter.Row, dMonth.Column)' I need string to range here
            End If
        End If
    Next dCostCenter
Next dMonth
```

Comment: Please explain the first line of code.  It appears you are just removing the leading character in a `String`.

Comment: where do you define DetailsCostCenters? I think you have a variant initially that then becomes a string.

Comment: Use a different variable.  Declare all your variables by the type you want them to be instead of letting them be of type Variant.

Comment: Yes, the first line is just to remove the leading zero from range `dCostCenter`, which is a part of `DetailsCostCenters` range set in other sub like that: `Set DetailsCostCenters = Range(DetailsFirstHeader.Offset(1, 0), DetailsLastCostCenter)`. After the removal the range dCostCenter becomes a string and cannot be used in the code that follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** possible to overload a variable, but it is very confusing to do so.  Say cell **B9** contains *abc*.  Then this code:

```
Sub OverLoad()
    Dim B9 As Range
    Set B9 = Range("B9")
    B9 = Right(B9, Len(B9) - 1)
    MsgBox B9 & vbCrLf & B9.Address
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- the contents of the cell does get clipped (the *a* gets removed)
- the Range variable `B9` still exists and can be used as a range
- the String variable `B9` exists and contains the clipped string

I suggest using separate variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add another variable, like dCostCenterString. Then use this when you convert your range to a string, leaving the original range available to use.
Also by not declaring your variables e.g

```
dim dCostCenterString as string
```

You are using variants, which can slow down your code and create errors as the vba has to guess what the variable is.